# Bootstrap dropdown menu always show and don't close

Tags: bootstrap-5

have a problem. I made a side menu dropdown menu. The dropdown li is always open. When I click on the dropdown in the browser show me he is working, but... [image: always open]

This is the code in the navbarComponent.html

```html
<nav class="navbar fixed-top  navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="z-index: 0;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"
            aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            <span>Produse</span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarTogglerDemo02">

            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 text-center">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-expanded="false">
                        Garduri
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/garduri">Garduri</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/placi-gard">Placi de gard</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/stalpi-gard">Stalpi de gard</a></li>
``                        </ul>
                </li>


                <li class="nav-item" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" routerLink="/gardulete-flori">Gardulete de flori</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" routerLink="/ghivece">Ghivece si Jarnidiere</a>
                </li>
              

            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

How can I close that dropdown ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do here.  `data-bs-toggle` is required on the dropdown’s trigger element, but you have it in 4 different locations (?)

Comment: it was a try for close the menu when i click on the li link from mobile device. it works, the menu is closing after select one li. but  the dropdown don't :(